# how to load an image to the playground

Tags: swift, file-upload, uiimageview, swift-playground

In the playground app, I am trying to upload an image, I google it and many solutions said that I need to put my image to resources. But the case is that in the new playground app, the is no resources folder that's why I couldn't add my image. There are shared Sources and Xcode sources but in these files, I couldn't put my image.

this can be an easy question but the case that I struggle with. And in order to continue my project, this point madden me. Thanks

as you can see, there aren't resources that ı could put my image
[image: as you can see, there aren't resources that ı could put my image]

there is space for adding an image but in this case, the problem is that after ı chose my image nothing happened

[image: there is space for adding an image but in this case, the problem is that after ı chose my image nothing happened]

Comment: It should work from Adding Image(2nd screen), Try with correct PNG format by "Insert From" action.

Comment: In this case, I got an errow. In decleration of "myScene" there is writing

Comment: Edit your post with the exact error message, please.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage` can be loaded to the `Playground` app like this,

1. File --> New Blank Playground.
2. Click on the '+" icon on the top right corner and choose the picture by clicking `Insert from...`  option.
3. Load the image with its name from the Playground.

   UIImage(named: "test.png")

[Output with loaded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiCvp.jpg)

Comment: yeah, but as I indicated in question the problem is that there is no resources file when I want to open my playground in Playgrounds App not XCode Playground. There is a difference. Btw thank you for your afford

Comment: I have edited  the answer and loaded image to Playgrounds app. Hope it helps !